# Create a single record from multidimensional input array's

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array

so for the backend i am using laravel and i have 3 inputs all with different names like this:

```
  <td><input class="input" type="text" name="p_color_name[]" placeholder="Red,  Blue etc.."></td>  

  <td><input class="input" type="text" name="p_color_price[]" placeholder="Price"></td>  

  <td><input class="input" type="text" name="p_color_stock[]" placeholder="Stock"></td>
```

The user has the ability to add more rows like the above and add data so the end result could be:

P_color_name = { red,blue}  p_color_price = {10,12} p_color_stock = {5,12}

So now i have 3 arrays and i want to create a single record for each row like:
red  10  5
blue 12 12

what i did is this:

```
 foreach ($request->p_color_name as $color_name) {
        $color_option = new ProductOption();
        foreach ($request->p_color_price as $color_price) {
            foreach ($request->p_color_stock as $color_stock) {

                $color_option->name = $color_name;

                $color_option->p_option_price = $color_price;

                $color_option->p_option_stock = $color_stock;
            }
        }  
         $product->productoption()->save($color_option);
         $option_type->productoption()->attach($color_option);    
    }
```

For 3 rows of data with the above code it gets the correct names and creates 3 different entries in the DB but for color_price and color_stock it only saves in all 3 entries the same data witch is from  the last row and complete skips the first 2 rows that it looped through.

How can i loop through and get the correct data for color_price and color_stock?

**SOLUTION:** [Here is the solution for the loop](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/create-a-single-record-from-multidimensional-input-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Use foreach(thing as $key => value), then use the $key to get the values from the other arrays at the same index. You only need one loop.

```
$prices = $request->p_color_price;
$names = $request->p_color_name;
$stocks = $request->p_color_stock;

foreach ($names as $key => $name) {
  $color_option = new ProductOption();

  $color_option->name = $name;
  $color_option->p_option_price = $prices[$key];
  $color_option->p_option_stock = $stocks[$key];

  // Save this $color_option
  $product->productoption()->save($color_option);
}
```

[Here is the link to laracasts post where a user solved it!](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/create-a-single-record-from-multidimensional-input-arrays)